# don't want.htaccess change my url link

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently creating multiple subdomain handeling system. I don'know how to set the `.htaccess` until I found this tutorial at [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoVcEqnqqbI).

I followed the original source code:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.your_domain.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).your_domain.com
    RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?name=%1 [L]
```

And I modify it to:

```
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mlaxproject.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).mlaxproject.com
    RewriteRule ^$ /sub_website/%1
```

It is almost completed; the URL takes me to the correct directory, but the only problem is that it reveals the sub directory at my URL:

> expect result : demos.mlaxproject.com
>  show result
>   :demos.mlaxproject.com/sub_website/demos/

How I would like it to be:

> demos.mlaxproject.com
>  test.mlaxproject.com
>   hello.mlaxproject.com

And not:

> demos.mlaxproject.com/sub_website/demos/
>   test.mlaxproject.com/sub_website/test/
>   hello.mlaxproject.com/sub_website/hello/

which is what I am getting,

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: You forgot the  [L]  at the end.

Comment: @bobdye  Thank for replay! with [L] also the same :( ...

Comment: Is that your full htaccess? Is there any other htaccess in sub-directory?